# Using async meteor.call() in meteor-react render() method

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor, reactjs, meteor-accounts

I am using Meteor and React for my app. in my app, i use account-ui, account-facebook to let user is able to sign in by using facebook account.
Now, i want to check if user is using facebook to sign-in Or regular user/pass to sign-in. I look at users collection and see that

```
1) if user used facebook to login, there is services.facebook in user collection
2) if user used regular user/pass to login, there is services.password  in users collection
```

in server, i have method to return loginservice (facebook or password)

```
Meteor.methods({
        getLoginService: function(){
            let services = Meteor.user().services;
            if (typeof services.facebook!=='undefined'){
                return 'facebook';
            }else if (typeof services.password!=='undefined'){
                return 'password';
            }
            return 'undefined';
        },
    });
```

In client side, if will check to see if that is (facebook login) Or (User/pass login), then i can render the screen accordingly

```
App.Components.Dashboard = React.createClass({

  render() {
    var lservice='';
    Meteor.call("getLoginService",function(error,service) {
      if (error){
      }else {
            lservice = service;
      }
    });

    if (lservice === 'facebook'){
        return (
            <div id="dashboard-content">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-lg-12">
                  <h1 className="page-header">Facebook connect</h1>
                  <p>put facebook information here</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        );



    }else{
        return (
            <div id="dashboard-content">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-lg-12">
                  <h1 className="page-header">Facebook connect</h1>
                  <p>put facebook connect button here</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        );
      }

  }
});
```

The problem is at client side. Because Meteor.call is async so that lservice will not get the value from callback function.
I also try to find a way to put html return into callback function(error, service) but not successful.

Do you know anyway to solve this problem. Or do you have any better idea to recognize what  service that user used to login (maybe a hook to account-facebook)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by moving your call to `Meteor.call` into `componentWillMount` so that it only runs once—just before the component is first rendered.

Code in your `render` method will be called each time that the state or props change and you probably only need to get the login service once.

Next, rather than storing the `service` string in a local variable, store it in `state` so that component renders each time it is updated.

```
getInitialState() {
  return {};
},
componentWillMount() {
  Meteor.call("getLoginService", (error, service) => {
    if(error) {
      // handle error
    } else {
      this.setState({ service });
    }
  });
},
render() {
  const { service } = this.state;

  if(service === 'facebook') {
    // return facebook view
  } else if(service === 'password') {
    // return password view
  } else {
    // return loading view
  }
}
```

The first time your application renders, the service probably won't be available (it'll be waiting for the request to come back), so it will render the loading view in the `else` clause.

However, when the callback is called (providing there are no errors), the state of the component will be updated and the component will re-render.

This time the service will be available and the correct view will be shown.

Comment: Thanks Dan Prince. I will use your code and see. Again, thanks so much for quick answer

Comment: Hi, i tried your code, and get back error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'service' of null.   If i put alert(service) after const {service} = this.state, i can see the value of service is correct but the error is still there and the page is not able to be rendered..

Comment: @David, you need to return an initial state for your component from `getInitialState` otherwise it will be `null` by default and you can't destructure `null` as an object. Updated answer.

Comment: I have used your code and put alert() to each line of code for debugging. What i can see is: componentWillMount will be executed first (BUT not completely -> callback method in Meteor.call is not triggered yet). Then render() gets invoked and  'service' gets 'undefined' value-> so i can not use 'service' to compare its value with 'facebook' and 'password'  --> render() always display loading view: Failed. After render() completed. Finally callback method is invoked and 'service' get correct value.   But at this time, render () already invoked to display 'loading view': which is not expected

Comment: There's no way to display the correct view until the data has loaded. This will happen on the second call to render and at this point `service` will have the correct value. You can either render a loading view or return `null` to render no component until then.

Comment: thanks for your patience. i am new to meteor and react. you say 2nd call to render(). If i refresh the screen many times, does that mean making 2nd, 3rd ... call to render(). i tried that way but the results are the same.

Comment: Any time you call `setState` you will trigger React to run the `render` method again and update the DOM (if there are any changes). Add a `console.log` statement to log the value of `service` in your `render` method, then see what value it logs, the second time it runs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104491/discussion-between-david-and-dan-prince).